# Are http requests automatically retrying tcp connections?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, distributed-computing, distributed

I'm building a distributed system in which i do some http requests to comunicate. I want the requests to be fault tolerant.  The requests has no timeout, should i retry the request after some period if i have no response or the http request is automatically retrying tcp connections? I used the library async http client in java. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ...  the http request is automatically retrying tcp connections?

The HTTP request is not a thing which can retry something by itself. A HTTP request is just data. It is up to the application to retry the request if something goes wrong. Some libraries used in applications might offer this, others not. Most don't since it is often not clear if the request should be retried in the first place since it might have unintended side effects if the web application receives the request twice (it might have received the first even though it gave no response).